# canonical-livepatch errors

Tags: canonical-livepatch

after installing ubuntu, i tried to enable livepatch but first i faced this error:

```
    error executing enable: cannot enable machine: bad temporary server status 500 (URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens) server response: machine token already exists
```

so i did `sudo rm /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && sudo systemd-machine-id-setup` and then `sudo rm /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && sudo systemd-machine-id-setup` but it brings me new error after i tried to enable livepatch again:

```
error executing enable: failed to read machine-id
```

Comment: @guiverc i am using Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS, isn't livepatch available for it?

Comment: It's not available for non-LTS releases; you're using a LTS release so it should be available; alas https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/ doesn't mention 20.04 as there is an issue there (which can be resolved I understand), but I know little about it sorry so cannot help.

Comment: @guiverc Thank You so much you already helped alot, i didn't know its only for LTS..., Thank you again.

Comment: so any body doesn't know anything...?